# error : matlab has encountered an internal error and needs to be close

Tags: matlab

I'm tryed to run boosting algorithm using SVM as classifier, there is the sample code :

```
 load('d:\xapp.mat');
 load('d:\yapp.mat');

 M = 10;
   cv = cvpartition(yapp, 'Kfold', 10);
   cv_accuracy = zeros(1, cv.NumTestSets);


for i = 1 : cv.NumTestSets
training = cv.training(i);
testing = cv.test(i);

x_training = xapp(training, :); y_training = yapp(training, :);
x_testing = xapp(testing, :); y_testing = yapp(testing, :);

models = cell(M, 1);
n = size(x_training, 1);
w = repmat(1 / n, n, M);
alpha = zeros(M, 1);
eps = zeros(M, 1);

for m = 1 : M

    models{m} = svmtrain(w(:, m) ./ min(w(:, m)), y_training, x_training, ' -c 1000 -g 10');

    predictions = svmpredict(y_training, x_training, models{m});

    I = (predictions ~= y_training);

    eps(m) = (w(:, m)' * I) / sum(w(:, m));
    alpha(m) = log ( (1 - eps(m)) / eps(m) );

    if m < M
        w(:, m + 1) = w(:, m) .* exp(alpha(m) * I);
    end
end

predictions = zeros(size(y_testing, 1), M);
for m = 1 : M
    predictions(:, m) = svmpredict(y_testing, x_testing, models{m});
end
  pred=mode(predictions,2);

cv_accuracy(i) = 100.*sum(pred == y_testing) / size(y_testing, 1);
 end

  fprintf('Accuracy => [%s]\nMean => %s\n', num2str(cv_accuracy), num2str(mean(cv_accuracy) * 100));
```

When I run this code, I got fequently the same error in this image.[image] I'm using matlab 2013b with window 7.Please, help me, any suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: `svmtrain` and `svmpredict` commands suggest that you may be using `libsvm` instead of MATALB's default SVM (which is totally fine). Now `libsvm` has mex files which have to be compiled properly. I have seen above error in cases where the program crashes inside a mex file. However, you need to narrow down the problem for us. First step would be to create a self-contained example i.e. which can be run as it is.

Comment: Also, your parameters are a bit weird. Try using `-c 32 -g 1` or the default ones.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar The problem is not in the estimation of parameters, I used earlier greatest parameters and it works very well. I did not understand why when I have used this program for the first time, it works as it should and it returns me good results but when I restart to run the same program ,I got this error.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar, I was edit the question to display detais of problem